Worse performance when using IN query
This query never finishes:
SELECT      *
FROM        logs
WHERE       user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY    create_time DESC
OFFSET      0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

But it works fast when I run query for each user:
SELECT      *
FROM        logs
WHERE       user_id = 1
ORDER BY    create_time DESC
OFFSET      0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

SELECT      *
FROM        logs
WHERE       user_id = 2
ORDER BY    create_time DESC
OFFSET      0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

SELECT      *
FROM        logs
WHERE       user_id = 3
ORDER BY    create_time DESC
OFFSET      0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

...
...

Of course there is an index: (user_id, create_time). How can I make it works fast without this workaround?
This is explain analyze of slow version:
Limit  (cost=3.97..910.15 rows=10 width=146) (actual time=20047.515..60926.287 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=3.97..13607492.42 rows=150164 width=146) (actual time=20047.511..60926.275 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: l.create_time DESC
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_08_create_time_idx on logs_2022_08 l_1  (cost=0.14..13.17 rows=1 width=150) (actual time=0.071..0.072 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 33
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_09_create_time_idx on logs_2022_09 l_2  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_10_create_time_idx on logs_2022_10 l_3  (cost=0.28..170.62 rows=13 width=129) (actual time=2.200..2.201 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2539
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_11_create_time_idx on logs_2022_11 l_4  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_12_create_time_idx on logs_2022_12 l_5  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_01_create_time_idx on logs_2023_01 l_6  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_02_create_time_idx on logs_2023_02 l_7  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_03_create_time_idx on logs_2023_03 l_8  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_04_create_time_idx on logs_2023_04 l_9  (cost=0.14..331.27 rows=13 width=732) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_05_create_time_idx on logs_2023_05 l_10  (cost=0.42..57850.64 rows=1228 width=136) (actual time=369.628..369.628 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 911143
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_06_create_time_idx on logs_2023_06 l_11  (cost=0.43..174034.93 rows=2227 width=136) (actual time=1041.777..1041.778 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2741483
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_07_create_time_idx on logs_2023_07 l_12  (cost=0.43..193774.34 rows=7559 width=136) (actual time=1142.189..1142.189 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3052669
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_08_create_time_idx on logs_2023_08 l_13  (cost=0.43..277219.15 rows=10433 width=128) (actual time=1633.194..1633.194 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 4435031
        ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_default_create_time_idx on logs_default l_14  (cost=0.57..12898500.97 rows=128612 width=148) (actual time=15858.387..56737.138 rows=10 loops=1)
              Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 195041011
Planning Time: 2.091 ms
Execution Time: 60926.450 ms

As requested, this is problem reproduction:
-- create table
CREATE TABLE public.logs (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    message varchar NULL,
    create_time timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (create_time);

-- create partitions
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2022_08 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-08-01 00:00:00') TO ('2022-09-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2022_09 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-09-01 00:00:00') TO ('2022-10-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2022_10 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-10-01 00:00:00') TO ('2022-11-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2022_11 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-11-01 00:00:00') TO ('2022-12-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2022_12 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-12-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-01-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_01 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-02-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_02 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-02-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-03-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_03 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-03-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-04-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_04 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-05-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_05 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-05-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-06-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_06 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-06-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-07-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_07 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-07-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-08-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_08 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-08-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-09-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_09 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-09-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-10-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_10 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-10-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-11-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_11 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-11-01 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2023_12 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-01-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_01 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-02-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_02 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-02-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-03-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_03 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-03-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-04-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_04 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-05-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_05 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-05-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-06-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_06 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-06-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-07-01 00:00:00');
CREATE TABLE public.logs_2024_07 PARTITION OF public.logs FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-07-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-08-01 00:00:00');

-- insert data
INSERT INTO public.logs
(user_id, message, create_time)
(
    select 
        random() * 70 + 10, 
        '',
        timestamp '2023-07-01 20:00:00' + random() * (timestamp '2024-07-01 20:00:00' - timestamp '2023-07-01 10:00:00')
    from generate_series(1,100000000)
)


-- create index
CREATE INDEX logs_user_id_create_time_idx ON ONLY public.logs USING btree (user_id, create_time);
CREATE INDEX logs_create_time_idx ON ONLY public.logs USING btree (create_time);

-- this executes in 42 seconds
SELECT
      l.*
FROM public.logs l
WHERE l.user_id in (62,63)
ORDER BY
    l.create_time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only


-- this executes in 2ms
SELECT
      l.*
FROM public.logs l
WHERE l.user_id = 62
ORDER BY
    l.create_time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

-- this executes in 2ms
SELECT
      l.*
FROM public.logs l
WHERE l.user_id = 63
ORDER BY
    l.create_time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY

Weird thing, I realized, that what @Charlieface suggestion is working on my reproduction table:
SELECT
  l.*
FROM (VALUES
    (62), (63)
) v(id)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      l.*
    FROM public.logs l
    WHERE l.user_id = v.id
    ORDER BY
      l.create_time DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
) l;

but when I do the same on my real table it is working slow. I see, that on my test table logs_user_id_create_time_idx index is used, but on my real table, logs_create_time_idx index is used.
reproduction table explain:
Nested Loop  (cost=7.30..25.36 rows=20 width=17) (actual time=0.018..0.059 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=7.30..12.57 rows=10 width=17) (actual time=0.012..0.027 rows=10 loops=2)
        ->  Append  (cost=7.30..748403.03 rows=1422618 width=17) (actual time=0.011..0.025 rows=10 loops=2)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_07_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_07 l_24  (cost=0.42..5261.62 rows=4849 width=17) (actual time=0.010..0.024 rows=10 loops=2)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_06_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_06 l_23  (cost=0.43..60415.82 rows=116442 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_05_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_05 l_22  (cost=0.43..62458.92 rows=120329 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_04_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_04 l_21  (cost=0.43..60460.24 rows=116451 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_03_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_03 l_20  (cost=0.43..62496.26 rows=120373 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_02_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_02 l_19  (cost=0.43..58442.66 rows=112568 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2024_01_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2024_01 l_18  (cost=0.43..62507.73 rows=120404 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_12_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_12 l_17  (cost=0.43..62496.97 rows=120381 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_11_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_11 l_16  (cost=0.43..60470.02 rows=116492 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_10_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_10 l_15  (cost=0.43..62483.80 rows=120368 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_09_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_09 l_14  (cost=0.43..60455.54 rows=116442 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_08_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_08 l_13  (cost=0.43..62491.76 rows=120376 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_07_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_07 l_12  (cost=0.43..60785.46 rows=117088 width=17) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_06_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_06 l_11  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_05_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_05 l_10  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_04_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_04 l_9  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_03_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_03 l_8  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_02_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_02 l_7  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_01_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2023_01 l_6  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_12_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2022_12 l_5  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_11_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2022_11 l_4  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_10_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2022_10 l_3  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_09_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2022_09 l_2  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_08_user_id_create_time_idx on logs_2022_08 l_1  (cost=0.15..5.74 rows=5 width=48) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
Planning Time: 0.419 ms
Execution Time: 0.123 ms

real table explain:
Limit  (cost=230.97..230.99 rows=10 width=147) (actual time=1270906.429..1270906.439 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=230.97..231.29 rows=130 width=147) (actual time=1270906.427..1270906.435 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: l.log_status_time DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.97..228.16 rows=130 width=147) (actual time=1080950.077..1270906.375 rows=17 loops=1)
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.16 rows=13 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.091 rows=13 loops=1)
              ->  Limit  (cost=3.97..17.34 rows=10 width=147) (actual time=95290.801..97762.012 rows=1 loops=13)
                    ->  Merge Append  (cost=3.97..10951049.45 rows=8192855 width=147) (actual time=95290.796..97762.006 rows=1 loops=13)
                          Sort Key: l.log_status_time DESC
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_08_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2022_08 l_1  (cost=0.14..8.42 rows=16 width=150) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_09_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2022_09 l_2  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_10_log_status_time_idx on logs_2022_10 l_3  (cost=0.28..135.71 rows=508 width=129) (actual time=0.782..0.782 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 2539
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_11_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2022_11 l_4  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2022_12_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2022_12 l_5  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_01_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2023_01 l_6  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_02_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2023_02 l_7  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_03_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2023_03 l_8  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_04_user_id_log_s_idx on logs_2023_04 l_9  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_05_log_status_time_idx on logs_2023_05 l_10  (cost=0.42..45322.43 rows=60743 width=136) (actual time=216.515..216.515 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 911143
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_06_log_status_time_idx on logs_2023_06 l_11  (cost=0.43..136339.54 rows=210883 width=136) (actual time=642.117..642.117 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 2741483
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_07_log_status_time_idx on logs_2023_07 l_12  (cost=0.43..151800.14 rows=277515 width=136) (actual time=709.320..709.321 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3052669
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_08_log_status_time_idx on logs_2023_08 l_13  (cost=0.43..216237.48 rows=295669 width=128) (actual time=1017.695..1017.695 rows=0 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 4435031
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_default_log_status_time_idx on logs_default l_14  (cost=0.57..10204218.54 rows=7347514 width=148) (actual time=92704.270..95175.480 rows=1 loops=13)
                                Filter: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 197830935
Planning Time: 1.687 ms
Execution Time: 1270906.754 ms

It looks like wrong index is being used, but I don't know why.
For example, this query:
select *
from public.logs_2022_11
where user_id in (62,63)
ORDER BY
    create_time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only

ran in a test table gives this explain analyze result:
Limit  (cost=9.89..9.92 rows=10 width=48) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=9.89..9.92 rows=11 width=48) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: create_time DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on logs_2022_11  (cost=1.48..9.70 rows=11 width=48) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{62,63}'::integer[]))
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on logs_2022_11_user_id_idx  (cost=0.00..1.48 rows=11 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{62,63}'::integer[]))
Planning Time: 0.210 ms
Execution Time: 0.032 ms

but on production table:
Limit  (cost=0.43..2049.72 rows=10 width=129) (actual time=1325.339..1325.340 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using logs_2023_08_log_create_time_idx on logs_2023_08 wl  (cost=0.43..216200.32 rows=1055 width=129) (actual time=1325.335..1325.336 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{62,63}'::integer[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 4435031
Planning Time: 0.263 ms
Execution Time: 1325.422 ms

EDIT
I realized, that its propably because on my production table, 99% total rows are from 15% users. In my test table, users ids were random.

you need to provide execution plan for the query

Please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement

You could try a join on a VALUES like FROM logs l JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) v(id) ON v.id = l.user_id Also these two queries do different things: one gets the top 10 per ID and the other gets the top 10 across the whole table. Which do you want?

Don't use IN if you are looking for a performant query.

The queries use a different index (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/JbMUztBD )

@Charlieface unfortunelly it works as bad as IN

@FrankHeikens I added execution plan

Drop the index on "time" or create custom statistics on the combination of user_id and time. Since you didn't share the settings, you might have to improve the configuration as well. The default configuration will most likely not be the right one for good performance.

Perhaps, your table partitioned and Therefore, if you run a query that does not include the partitioning key, even if there is an index created for whatever predicate you used, PostgreSQL can’t use it to reduce the surface area it has to search. Is your table partitioned and if yes, what is partitioning key (created_time?) ?

You didn't answer my other question: the two queries do different things, which do you want?

It would be interesting to see the execution plan of one of the fast queries.

As per @charlieface, please confirm the desired behaviour (as your two code snippets do not do the same thing)

@MatBailie I want 10 rows over whole table. I know that my example with 10 rows per every user was giving wrong results, but it is easy to fix. The problem is related with slow query

using edit to provide a solution ("I realized, that its propably because.....") is not how stackoverflow.com is working. (see: Can answer my own question )

These queries do different things. The first query gets the top 10 rows across the whole table, which means the index cannot be used effectively. While the second query get the top 10 rows per user_id.
You could use a lateral join to simulate the second query, and for this your existing index will be used efficiently.
SELECT
  l.*
FROM (VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
) v(id)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      l.*
    FROM logs l
    WHERE l.user_id = v.id
    ORDER BY
      l.create_time DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
) l;

An alternative way to pass multiple values is
FROM unnest('{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]) AS v(id)

If you actually do want the top 10 rows over the whole table then use the full query above, but add another OFFSET FETCH
ORDER BY
  l.create_time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;

If the VALUES clause is very large then you should dump all the values into a temp table and CROSS JOIN LATERAL with that instead.

I think your additional ORDER BY should not be ordering by v.id, but just by create_time desc.  That seems to be most consistent with his original query.

fixed that now thanks

@Charlieface This looks grat, but I am getting an error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "LATERAL" (PostgreSQL 13.3),

sorry got the syntax wrong see edit

Now syntax is correct, but unfortunelly it is as slow as IN, still waiting over 5 minutes for a explain analyze results :(. Maybe I should mention this earlier, but logs is a partition table, partitioned on create_time.

Is it a very large VALUES? Maybe use an actual temp table.

13 VALUES, 300 000 000 rows in a logs table, 19 rows as a query result

@dafie please include the full table definition, in your question, including partitioning, etc, to avoid all doubt.

@MatBailie I included problem reproduction

@Charlieface On a fresh new table, with generated data your suggestion works great, but when I try to use it on my production table, which is basically the same as my test table, wrong index is being used. Still wondering why

A better solution is to never use things that are iterative... Including IN...
So try :
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T (I INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

SELECT      *
FROM        logs AS l
            JOIN T ON l.user_id = T.I
ORDER BY    create_time DESC
OFFSET      0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS only


Why (is this a better solution) ?  Please add some reference .

@SQLPro unfortunelly it works as bad as IN
